# what is the benefit of <em> vs <i>?

Tags: html

I have heard that using the newer `<strong>` tag as opposed to `<b>` creates an ability for some devices to make text "strong" that was already bolded-as in the case of a palm pilot, where it would be underlined if you used `<strong>`.

I have also heard that older browsers cannot recognize `<strong>` and `<em>` and just ignore them, but newer browsers recognize both the old and new tags, making it an advantage to use the older tags if your users/viewers might have old browsers-however some newer devices benefit from the newer tag (like the `<strong>` vs `<b>`).

So I was wondering-how does the `<em>` tag show up on, say, a palm pilot, or similar devices?

What is the advantage and disadvantage of using `<em>` vs `<i>`? Or vice-versa?

~Added after comments and marked as "duplicate"~

Since this *seems* to some to be a duplicate question, but I can't find my answer, I will rephrase:

1. What would happen to text in a browser that did not recognize the < i > tag if you used that instead of the < em > tag? How would it appear?
2. Is there any *advantage* to using the < i > tag that now appears to be less "correct" to use then the < em > tag? For instance-some devices might recognize it but not the other? Or would it be pretty much obsolete and useless?

Comment: "Newer"? Both appeared in HTML 2, which is almost twenty years old.

Comment: Does anyone still care about palm pilots? :)

Comment: There's an argument to say you shouldn't use either anymore. CSS should dictate what the style is not HTML.

Comment: I was told it was newer to use the < em > vs the < i >-and I did not argue, but accepted that was why there were two that seemed to do the same, and why the first time I studied html no mention was made of < em > in any place I looked it up, but now you have that given as the default. Idk if anyone cares about palm pilots, again, when I was researching the difference between the "old" and "new" ways of coding for bold or strong and italics, the example was given that if your reader was using a device that already bolded all text (such as a palm pilot) the bold tag would be useless, whereas...

Comment: ...whereas  the strong tag would have meaning, and the device would underline that text.  I simply wondered what would happen in similar scenario if the italic tag was used, what difference could it make?

Comment: I have read your answers and the answers below to what you are saying are duplicate questions, but I cannot find the answer to what I asked, so I went back and added to my original question in an attempt to clarify what I want to know, because it does not appear to me to be a duplicate or answered anywhere here.

Comment: A screen reader will pronounce the words in <em> with an emphasis, using verbal stress.

Answer (score 32):

It's about semantics.  Using `strong` or `em` means that the contents of the tag have more emphasis than the nearby copy.

Bolding or italicizing stuff is just formatting.  And formatting belongs in css, not html.

Comment: `<i>` is commonly used for icons these days e.g.[https://fontawesome.com/](https://fontawesome.com/) I personally use `<i>` for icons and `<em>` for italic

Answer (score 20):

The purpose of HTML is to mark up text *semantically*, meaning to give it *meaning*. This is explicitly separate from *presentation*, which is to be handled by CSS.

`i` has the purpose of *presenting* something in *italicised style*.
`em` has the purpose of giving *em*phasis to the content.

In practice emphasised content is typically displayed italicised, so the difference on the face of it is non-existing from a presentation standpoint. However, *emphasis* is semantic while *italics* is presentation. <strike>`i` was deprecated in favour of `em`</strike> to make HTML a truly semantic markup. It may seem like nitpicking, but at least it's thorough.

Comment: They have not been deprecated.

Comment: You are right. I seem to misremember. Or has it been undeprecated at some point?

Comment: [WHATWG - Why are some presentational elements like b, i and small still included?](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#Why%5Fare%5Fsome%5Fpresentational%5Felements%5Flike%5F.3Cb.3E.2C%5F.3Ci.3E%5Fand%5F.3Csmall.3E%5Fstill%5Fincluded.3F)

Comment: Updated address of the FAQ in the comment above: https://github.com/whatwg/html/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-are-some-presentational-elements-like-b-i-and-small-still-included

Comment: A screen reader will pronounce the words in <em> with an emphasis, using verbal stress.